# How many words are enough to confirm user backed up all words for seed phrase?

Tags: security, mnemonic-seed, seed, wallet-development

If there are 12 words in the seed phrase, is confirming random 3 words enough to ensure user has backed up all words?

Or is it necessary to confirm all words and in the correct order?

[image: seed-words]

[image: confirm-seed]

If I create a new wallet it would ask me for other 3 words:

[image: confirm-seed]

Comment: You may be interested in the Bitcoin Design Guide: https://bitcoin.design/guide/onboarding/backing-up-a-wallet/

Comment: imo best option is to confirm all 12 words - I do not understand how checking just 3-4 as link above recommends is enough

Comment: Some horrible ideas at that site, best to ignore anything that author writes